# Roll component in UIPickerView (xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

Is there any chance to make a UIPickerView roll its components automatically by pushing button or changing another row in component? I mean I have two components in UIPickerView and when I choose in first one I want the second one to roll automatically to another object. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and even easy - all you have to do is to implement the following method of `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (row==3 && component==1) [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
}
```